# Retrieving data from http web call in flutter into a list object always empty

Tags: flutter, dart

List is always empty even though body has contents. I am new to flutter so bare with me if this is basic. I am wanting to get back a list of station data I am coming from a c# background so forgive me if am missing something simple the test string body has the items and can see the items when i debug

```
 class HttpService {
  final String url = "url hidden";
  final String host = 'url hidden';
  final String apiSegment = "api/";

// ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  void login(email, password) async {
    try {
      Map<String, String> body = {
        'username': email,
        'password': password,
      };

      Map<String, String> headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
      final msg = jsonEncode(body);

      Response response =
          await post(Uri.parse("$url/Login"), headers: headers, body: msg);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
        print(data['jwtToken']);
        print('Login successfully');

        final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

        await prefs.setString('jwtToken', data['jwtToken']);

        List<Stations> stationData = await getStationData('11');
        var test = stationData;
      } else {
        print('failed');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<List<Stations>> getStationData(String stationId) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String? token = prefs.getString('jwtToken');
    const String path = 'Station/GetAllStationData';

    final uri = Uri.parse('$url/api/$path')
        .replace(queryParameters: {'stationId': stationId});

    List<Stations> stationData = <Stations>[];
    try {
      Response res = await get(uri, headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        // 'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      });

      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        var body = jsonDecode(res.body);
        var body2 = body.toString();

        stationData = body
            .map(
              (dynamic item) => Stations.fromJson(item),
            )
            .toList();
      } else {
        throw "Unable to retrieve posts.";
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    return stationData;
  }
}
```

I am calling my function from the same class

```
List<Stations> stationData = await getStationData('11');
```

Data from body

[image]

Comment: Check your catch branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is you are returning the data after the end of `try catch`.
Try this

```
Future<List<Stations>> getStationData(String stationId) async {
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final String? token = prefs.getString('jwtToken');
const String path = 'Station/GetAllStationData';

final uri = Uri.parse('$url/api/$path')
    .replace(queryParameters: {'stationId': stationId});
try {
  Response res = await get(uri, headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    // 'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
  });

  if (res.statusCode == 200) {
    var body = jsonDecode(res.body);
    

 final stationData =  List<Stations>.from(body.map((item) => Stations.fromJson(item))); // made some changes
    return stationData;
  } else {
    throw "Unable to retrieve posts.";
  }
} catch (e) {
  rethrow;
  } 
}
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: That was it 100% it was always going be returning null thanks